# Shouldn't the startIndex be one?

Tags: java, list, indexing, data-structures, cisco

I am doing a tutorial on how to use the Cisco APIC EM Reference API
Here is where I currently am in the tutorial

[image]

Here is the actual API Documentation for that method - from the [APIC-EM API Docs](https://developer.cisco.com/site/apic-em/documents/api-reference/).

[image]

To get a list of the first 3 hosts, the tutorial specified a start index of 1.

Off just reading the API documentation, how would you know that the first element(host) is at index 1, not 0?  In Java, indexed based structures like List(ArrayList, LinkedList) are zero indexed. Is it different when working with APIs?

Comment: In JDBC, on the other hand, you index your parameters from 1. It's an implementation detail that varies from programmer to programmer. It should be mentioned in the documentation. But not all documentations are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is zero based, however there are exceptions and they are explicitly stated in the documentation. The only solution without documentation is the old trial and error method.